# Date module text between start and end date

Tags: views, datetime

I'm wondering if it's possible to change the "to"-text between a start date and an end date.

I'm only using years, for instance I want to change the following line: "1925 to 1928"
To this line "1925 - 1928".

I'm using drupal views, and this specific information is presented in a grid system.

Where can I change this?

Comment: Where is this 'to'?  Is it an exposed filter?

Comment: Asked again http://drupal.stackexchange.com/q/86900/16495 - when one will have answers, other should get closed as a duplicate.

Comment: Added an answer to the other post @Mołot, which would apply to this question as well.

Comment: @ScottJoudry Seen it added, seen it upvoted and voted for a duplicate before you commented :P

Comment: You're too fast for me!